# Redirect subdomain of one domain to a subdomain of another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect the following (respectively):

```
http://sub.firstdomain.com/d/(all_files_and_folders)
http://sub.firstdomain.com/d2/(all_files_and_folders)
```

to

```
http://sub.seconddomain.com/d/(all_files_and_folders)
http://sub.seconddomain.com/d2/(all_files_and_folders)
```

There are other files and folders under the first subdomain that I do not want redirected.  Previously this was working but now it seems like Go Daddy changed something and what I had is no longer working.  Here it is:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^stats/(.+) /dstats/count.php?statspage=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.deb$  /dstats/count.php?file=$1.deb [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.
RewriteRule ^(d2?)/(.*)$ http://sub.seconddomain.com/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

You can ignore the RewriteRule.  It is working fine.  I wanted to make sure I included the entire .htaccess file just in case.  My issue is with RewriteCond it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /d/ http://sub.seconddomain.com/d/
Redirect 301 /d2/ http://sub.seconddomain.com/d2/
```

The above should only redirect anything in the `/d/` and `/d2/` folder of the `sub` subdomain.

EDIT: Second try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.
RewriteRule ^(d2?)/(.*)$ http://sub2.mydomain.com/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working either for some reason. Shouldn't the page automatically redirect to the other domain?

Comment: Where is the htaccess file located? Is it in the root directory of the  sub domain?

Comment: Yes. Root of the subdomain: